# Applying click function through delegate on selected div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to add opposite of Not of jquery?

```
<div class="line-item">
<div class="thumb">
    Image goes here
</div>
<div class="title">
    Title goes here
</div>
<div class="destroy">
    Destroy Button goes here
</div>
```

here is the Java Script

```
$('div.line-item').delegate('div:not(".destroy")', 'click', function() {
alert('hi');
})
```

What i want is to apply "click" on just that div having .destroy class

here is the working Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/110/

Comment: Why not simply `$('div.line-item').on('click', '.destroy', ...` ?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: I think it's important to appreciate that there could be reasons why someone has to use an older version of a library. just sayin' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would that achieve what you need ?

```
$('div.line-item').delegate('div:not(".destroy")', 'click', function() {
    alert('hi');
}).delegate(".destroy", 'click', function(){
    alert('bye');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/112/

Alternatively:

```
$('div.line-item').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is(".destroy")){
        alert("bye");
    }else{
        alert("hi");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/113/

Answer (score 2):

Use a newer version of jQuery and do :

```
$('div.line-item').on('click', '.destroy', function() {
//    ^^ static parent | ^^ event | ^^ dynamic element bound to handler
    alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: The fiddle uses jQuery 1.5 (not sure OP meant to, but it does), which does not have `.on()`

Comment: @techfoobar - then an upgrade is in order.

Comment: Yes, 1.5 is too old. OP needs to ensure however that he is not dependant on other code/plugin thats hardlocked to one of the features removed after 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('div.line-item').delegate('.destroy', 'click', function() {
    alert('hi');
})
```

as in this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/111/)**

Comment: `.on()`should be used instead of `delegate()`

Comment: @wumm - The fiddle uses jQuery 1.5, which doesn't have `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.line-item').on('click', '.destroy', function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

If you are using a newer version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for binding the click event without using delegate.

```
 $('.line-item > .destroy').click(function(){
        //your code goes here
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trVKF/114/)**